# blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/OpenEXR.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN13IlmThread_3_14TaskE

Tags: 22.04, python, blender, openexr

I am trying to install OpenEXR Python package in Ubuntu 22.04 using bundled Python 3.10 that comes with Blender 3.5.

```
(base) mona@ada:~/pvnet-rendering$ /home/mona/Downloads/blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/bin/python3.10 run.py --type rendering
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/run.py", line 24, in <module>
    globals()['run_' + args.type]()
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/run.py", line 11, in run_rendering
    from blender.render_utils import Renderer, YCBRenderer
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/blender/render_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    import OpenEXR
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenEXR'
(base) mona@ada:~/pvnet-rendering$ /home/mona/Downloads/blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/bin/pip  install openexr
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting openexr
  Downloading OpenEXR-1.3.9-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (534 bytes)
Downloading OpenEXR-1.3.9-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.2/1.2 MB 9.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
DEPRECATION: pytorch-lightning 1.6.0 has a non-standard dependency specifier torch>=1.8.*. pip 24.0 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to upgrade to a newer version of pytorch-lightning or contact the author to suggest that they release a version with a conforming dependency specifiers. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12063
Installing collected packages: openexr
Successfully installed openexr-1.3.9
(base) mona@ada:~/pvnet-rendering$ /home/mona/Downloads/blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/bin/python3.10 run.py --type rendering
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/run.py", line 24, in <module>
    globals()['run_' + args.type]()
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/run.py", line 11, in run_rendering
    from blender.render_utils import Renderer, YCBRenderer
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/blender/render_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    import OpenEXR
ImportError: /home/mona/Downloads/blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/OpenEXR.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN13IlmThread_3_14TaskE
```

How should I fix this error?

Comment: It is not recommended to do `/home/mona/Downloads/blender-3.5.1-linux-x64/3.5/python/bin/python3.10 run.py`. It is recommended to install the official version of blender by using `sudo apt install blender`, then starting blender from the applications menu

Comment: @DanielT can you please be a bit more specific? is there a tutorial for this? I am not really sure how to make use of the bundled Python inside Blender. Thank you

Comment: What I meant is that downloading a Blender bundle is discouraged on Ubuntu. It is recommended use a Blender package that *does not contain* any bundled version of Python.

Comment: After hours of trying, I believe there is likely a glibc or C++ ABI incompatibility between '3.5/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/OpenEXR.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so' and 'lib/libIex.so'. Your earlier _ZTIN13IlmThread_3_14TaskE error is fixable with `LD_PRELOAD`ing zlib and a bunch of libraries from ./lib, but the last one doesn't go away. For `void throwErrnoExc (const std::string& text)`, one library names it _ZN7Iex_3_113throwErrnoExcERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEi.cold but the other one is looking for _ZN7Iex_3_113throwErrnoExcERKSs

Answer (score 2):

This version of Blender's bundled OpenEXR libraries conflict with the prebuilt OpenEXR wheel on PyPI.

The simplest alternative is to install that wheel on Ubuntu 23.04 or Ubuntu 23.10. Ubuntu 22.10 and lower have version 2 instead of the version 3 that the wheel requires. Start with `sudo apt install openexr python3-venv`. Then this following works:

```bash
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install OpenEXR
python3 -c 'import OpenEXR'
# No error from Python
```

The ultimate reason the wheel won't work is that the Blender version wants `void throwErrnoExc (const std::string& text)` to be called `_ZN7Iex_3_113throwErrnoExcERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEi`, but the PyPI wheel is looking for _ZN7Iex_3_113throwErrnoExcERKSs. This looks like a glibc or C++ ABI problem, caused by the libraries being built with different compilers or other environmental differences.

Fixing the `_ZTIN13IlmThread_3_14TaskE` does not help. You can fix a series of errors with `LD_PRELOAD=lib/libIlmThread.so:lib/libImath.so:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so 3.5/python/bin/python3.10 -c 'import OpenEXR'`. Sadly, the final `_ZN7Iex_3_113throwErrnoExcERKSs` error is unfixable without rebuilding Blender, therefore using Ubuntu 23.04  or higher and the officially packaged Blender version in the repositories is easier.

Comment: If I can't change my Ubuntu version, is there a version of OpenEXR or Blender that I can use ? Thank you